# use if inside qml row element failed

Tags: qml

I add a property cond in Row element,so when cond is true, it will draw 3 picture,otherwise only one will be drawed

but qml report "Unexpected token `if'" ,any ideas? Thanks

```
import QtQuick 1.1

Rectangle{
id:rect
    property bool cond:true;
    Row{
     Image{ source:"good.png" }
     if(cond) {
         Image{ source:"good.png" }
         Image{ source:"good.png" }
     }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is [syntactically](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qdeclarativeintroduction.html) wrong: QML structure description statements cannot be wrapped in javascript code.

But the solution is simple:

```qml
import QtQuick 1.1

Rectangle {
    id:rect
    property bool cond: true;
    Row{
        Image{ source:"good1.png" }

        // show image elements only if 'cond' is true
        Image{ source:"good2.png"; visible: cond }
        Image{ source:"good3.png"; visible: cond }
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can create the image elements [dynamically](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qdeclarativedynamicobjects.html#creating-a-component-dynamically), but this is more complex.